Create a minimal Lwip UDP echo server fails
I'm unfamiliar with LightWeight IP, but I am trying to learn how to use it. First I want to create a simple UDP echo server.
To achieve this I use the code from the lwip/contrib/apps/udpecho_raw
But I only get the following error: Error creating UDP pcb (This error is generated in the function udpecho_raw_init)
Which functions do I have to call so that this error does not occur? What do I do wrong?
My two use cases:

Send a UDP message
Receive a UDP message

Currently my implementation runs on Ubuntu.
static struct udp_pcb *udpecho_raw_pcb;

static void udpecho_raw_recv(void *arg, struct udp_pcb *upcb, struct pbuf *p,
                 const ip_addr_t *addr, u16_t port)
{
  LWIP_UNUSED_ARG(arg);
  printf("udpecho_raw_recv\n");
  if (p != NULL) {
    /* send received packet back to sender */
    printf("udpecho_raw_recv: received the following UDP data: %s\n", (char *)p->payload);
    udp_sendto(upcb, p, addr, port);
    /* free the pbuf */
    pbuf_free(p);
  }
}

void udpecho_raw_init(void)
{
  udpecho_raw_pcb = udp_new_ip_type(IPADDR_TYPE_ANY);
  if (udpecho_raw_pcb != NULL) {
    err_t err;

    err = udp_bind(udpecho_raw_pcb, IP_ANY_TYPE, 7);
    if (err == ERR_OK) {
      udp_recv(udpecho_raw_pcb, udpecho_raw_recv, NULL);
      printf("UDP echo server started on port 7\n");
    } else {
      printf("Error on udp_bind: %d\n", err);
    }
  } else {
    printf("Error creating UDP pcb\n");
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  udpecho_raw_init();
  return 0;
}

